# How to call method in class variable?

Tags: php, class, methods

Say I want to set a class variable equal to (to keep things simple):

```
public $variable = strtolower('Dog');
```

When I try to do anything like this, I get: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' ...

I'm sure this is an amateur mistake, but I've searched the forum and Google and cannot find an answer to this anywhere. How can I call a built-in (proper terminology?) method within a class variable?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initialize class properties to constant values, but not call a function.  You can however do that within a constructor.

```
class Test {
    public $var1 = 'Dog';  // <-- This is allowed
    public $var2 = strtolower('Dog'); // <-- This is not allowed

    public function __construct() {
        $this->var2 = strtolower('Dog');
    }
}
```

From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php):

> This declaration may include an initialization, but this
>   initialization must be a constant value--that is, it must be able to
>   be evaluated at compile time and must not depend on run-time
>   information in order to be evaluated.